# Docker | Nginx build php service not found

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I am trying to create a customer dockerfile for my `nginx` and my `php-fpm`, so they can be reused whenever I want to have them.

I have gotten so far but I have hit a wall at the minute.

I have a Dockerfile which builds up the nginx image and adds configs and env variables to the config which seems to be working flawlessly.

However, as I have php-fpm in another file to enable php mods that I need it's not being picked up by the nginx config so I'm getting the error

> host not found in upstream "php_service"

Is what I'm trying to do even possible or would I have to bake the php into the nginx image as well (which I wanted to avoid if possible, so if I need to transfer over to apache I can use the same image)

Comment: Using `docker-compose`? What does your `docker-compose.yml` look like?

Comment: I have fixed this issue now @waterloomatt but I have another issue that the dockerfile is exiting with code 0

Comment: Exit code 0 usually means everything went OK. You still didn't show your compose.yml file.